# Splitting a string array into a double array and calculating the average of all the values in java

Tags: java

I am trying to split a String array (1.29\r1.31\r1.30\r1.29\r1.30\r1.30\r1.31\r1.27\r1.28\r1.27\r1.25\r1.29\r) and then assign the values to a double array which would then compute the average of all the values.
My code:

```
    public void process(String data) {
        int length = 0;
        double  total = 0; 


        String[] split = data.split("\r");

        // create double array while ignoring the first element 
        double[] numbers = new double[split.length-1];

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers .length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = Double.parseDouble(split[i+1]);
            total = total + numbers[i]; //Adds the array value to the total
            length = length + 1;
        }
        averageRate = total / length; //Equation used to compute the average
    }
```

The output:

```
1.29\r1.31\r1.30\r1.29\r1.30\r1.30\r1.31\r1.27\r1.28\r1.27\r1.25\r1.29\r

Average computed: NaN
Now let's do some conversion...
£100.0 gets us on average $NaN
$100.0 gets us on average £NaN
```

Comment: Have you tried to escape the backslash, like `data.split("\\r")`?

Comment: @deHaar I tried that and the output stayed the same.

Comment: Where are you getting that `String` from? It does not look like an array, more like something read from a file.

Comment: Try using : ```data.split("\\\\r");```

Comment: Why are you subtracting 1 from the `numbers[]` array initialized length? Oh...and the regular expression is fine the way it is

Answer (score 1):

The Regular Expression you're using for your **String#split()** method should be fine the way it is:

```
String data = "1.29\r1.31\r1.30\r1.29\r1.30\r1.30\r1.31\r1.27\r1.28\r1.27\r1.25\r1.29\r";
String[] splitData = data.split("\r");
double[] dblArray = new double[splitData.length];
for (int i = 0; i < splitData.length; i++) {
    dblArray[i] = Double.parseDouble(splitData[i]);
}
    
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dblArray));
```

Now all you need to do is sum up the the double type values in the array (while in the `for` loop) and divide by `dblArray.length` to get the average (after the `for` loop).

Answer (score -1):

```
String input = "1.29\r1.31\r1.30\r1.29\r1.30\r1.30\r1.31\r1.27\r1.28\r1.27\r1.25\r1.29\r";
    double avg = Arrays.stream(input.split("\r"))
          .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(a -> Double.parseDouble(a)));
    System.out.println(avg);
```